# How to remove important comments when using google closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I'm using CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS

raw js:

```
/* aaaaaaaaaaa */
const arrA = [1, 2, 3];//some comments
const arrB = [...arrA, 4, 5];
/*! This is important */
const objA = {
     foo: "bar" //coments here
};
const objB = {
    ...objA,
    qaz: "wsx"
}
```

after compiled:

```
/*
 This is important */
'use strict';const arrA=[1,2,3],arrB=[...arrA,4,5],objA={foo:"bar"},objB={...objA,qaz:"wsx"};
```

Can I set some option to force remove the important comments?

Thanks